What should I do if Asset in Unity 2D has changed the operation of some components?
I wanted to take the light from the Asset that I downloaded, but when I imported it, this asset added new layers, removed some tags, changed the operation of Gravity Scale in Physics 2D and Material, whose shader is located along the Sprites/Diffuse path (that is, when the object in the Sprite Renderer component has this material then if Sprite Renderer/flipX = false, then it becomes transparent, the same will happen if the object in Transform/Scale = -0.1 and <). Because of this, the game broke down (well, technically it only works the wrong way) and I want to roll back my actions or fix the problem in some other way.How can I do this?
if necessary, the game is based on the Unity 2020 version.3.26f1 (64-bit).

reverft to the before time in your source control?
